# /root partition full

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, root, disk-usage

I have a Desktop PC that I rarely use. Today I booted up this PC to do the updates and to organize some folders but reading my conky I saw that the `/` (root) partition is almost full. I have 23 GB of this and 20 GB are used. These are my partitions:
[image]

On my lapotop I have the same programs and the same space of `root` partition but I have got only 4 GB used. 
How can I solve this problem, I think that is impossible to have 20 GB files in `/` . Where and what I have to check for solve? thank you

with `sudo baobab` allow my to see a big file in desktop that I didn't able to see with nothing. Now my root partition, now I have 13 GB used instead of 20. I post 2 pictures with the files that fill the partition. 
[image]

[image]

these are the kernel image right? How can I delete them (I remember that some time ago I deleted these files with very bad results)?

Comment: You can visualise what's taking the space using `sudo baobab`. May be the cached apt-get packages. Try running `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: The following command will help figure out where the space is: `du -s /* 2>/dev/null | sort -nr`. You may want to add its output to the question for review.

Comment: @mikewhatever That's slow, but I learned something new. Any way to get it to do its thing based on individual files instead of directories?

Comment: I edited my answer with new informations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have way too many kernels and headers installed. I'd recommend removing all, but the most recent. There are several ways to do it, I like this one:

```
dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | grep -E "(image|headers|modules)" | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

[...explained here](http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/)

Other then that, I see nothing obviously wrong. What you have on the desktop should add up to the home partition, and not /.

Comment: Thanks for the command, I deleted all the old kernels, now root partition uses only 5 GB.  I don't know why, but under the `/` partition with `sudo baobab` command has showed the desktop folder and after clean it the space on root partition was clean.